# Listview filter is being ignored by onResume()

Tags: java, android

I have a `Listview` showing all of my data from a database. I currently have a filter `onTextChanged` method that filters a user inputted string. This works perfectly until I override the `onResume()` method of the activity class. I have used this `onResume()` to reload the `Listview` when the user clicks the back button.

As stated without the `onResume` it functions perfectly. With the onResume() the filter is blocked.

Here's my code:

```
public class view extends ListActivity {

    ImageButton searchButton;
    EditText searchName;
    ListView searchedListResults;
    long idToPass;
    String numReturned;
    String email;
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        list();
    }

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    DBHandler getCons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        searchedListResults = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        list();

        searchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);

        searchedListResults.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        searchName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                // list();
                searchedListResults.refreshDrawableState();

            }

        });

        getCons = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

        cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                getCons.open();
                return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());

            }

        });
        searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }

    private void list() {
        DBHandler DBsearchRef = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

        DBHandler search = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

        search.open();
        Cursor cursor = search.getData();
        search.close();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { DBsearchRef.KEY_NAME,
                DBsearchRef.KEY_TEL, DBsearchRef.KEY_EMAIL,
                DBsearchRef.KEY_COMMENTS };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtNameSet, R.id.txtContactSet,
                R.id.txtEmailSet, R.id.txtCommentSet };

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.searchagain,
                cursor, from, to);
        searchedListResults.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove list() in onResume(). onResume() is called when activity is resumed. You came back to the same activity it is resumed. Activity is also recreated when device orientation changes. So need to take care of that situation also.

Comment: notifydatasetchange on resume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As stated without the onResume it functions perfectly. With the onResume() the filter is blocked.

The difference between calling `list()` in  `onCreate()` and in `onResume()` is that you only set a FilterQueryProvider in `onCreate()`.  So when create a new CursorAdapter in `onResume()` it *doesn't* have a filter...

---

**Tips**

If you move:

```
cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        getCons.open();
        return getCons.getChanges(constraint.toString());
    }
});
```

into `list()`, then your code will behave as expected.

---

> If i remove the onresume method then i end up with a blank listview when back is clicked.

If you ever have data that "disappears" when you return to an Activity, then you must save it yourself in [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).  They're quite simple to use, here's a Developer's Guide on [Recreating an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

---

Lastly, you don't need to call `list()` in *both* `onResume()` and `onCreate()`, it does the same thing in both places.  Currently it doesn't add any features that change after `onCreate()` so you can remove your `onResume()` method entirely.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject. Also  when screen orientation changes you can use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). Also check the link especialy the topic under Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change.

Comment: @Sam A great piece of information there that Im sure will benefit us all. I can see how my onResume is in affect redundant.I i override the SaveInstanceState and RestoreInstanceState methods do i actually need to pass them anything? I have read the android document and it seems that the created bundle handles all of the screen changing when the activity is recreated.

Comment: I'm don't understand exactly what you mean by "do i actually need to pass them anything?" I could answer that many different ways... Click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15478659/edit) below your question and add what you are currently using. Then post a comment here, so I know you've done this.

Comment: @user1352057 Ok, I understood that. In `onSave...()` do you use: `savedInstanceState.putString("search", searchName.getText().toString());` then use: `searchName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("search"));` in `onRestore...()`. When you do the EditText's TextWatcher _should_ call your ListView's filter and the ListView should show the appropriate values...

Comment: @Sam I'm 99% sure Ive achieved exactly what Im after using your explanation on the fact I don't have a filter set on the onResume method. I have just tried it by adding one as a test and it works.